# Titles & capital letters

Tags: capitalization

The sentence contains the phrase, 'It would have to be OK'd by The Superintendent.'
My second sentence contains the phrase, ' ... being followed by the assistant manager.'
I'm not sure if I should use capital letters for The Superintendent & the Assistant Manager.'
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why would you capitalize the superintendent?

Answer (score 1):

Titles are not capitalized unless they're part of the name. You would write

> Yesterday, **the president** addressed the press.

but

> Yesterday, **President Obama** addressed the press.

and

> I have a question for you, **Mr. President.**

Also, "the" and other articles are never capitalized, even in a title, unless it's the first word in the title or sentence (for example: *[The Sound and the Fury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sound_and_the_Fury),* by William Faulkner).

Comment: *The sound and the fury* ?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether it is a title (ie. Hello Teacher!) or just a description (ie. I gave it to my teacher). A title would be capitalised, a description would not.

Comment: Don't neglect the possibility that it is a name.  After all, who can forget *Catch 22*'s Major Major Major Major.

Comment: True, true. And I'm sure there are other possibilities.